# Why does JQuery not work in IE and FireFox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I test in Chrome and Safari and It's work properly. It only go up the first condition. 
Did i do something wrong? Sorry..but I'm very new in JQuery.I use jQuery v1.9.1 and IE11  Here is the script:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".next").click(function () {
            var position = $('body').scrollTop();
            if (position == 0) {
                jQuery('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: 642
                });
            } else if (position >= 0 && position <= 642) {
                jQuery('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: 1735
                });
            } else if (position >= 642 && position <= 1735) {
                jQuery('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: 2403
                });
            } else if (position >= 1735 && position <= 2403) {
                jQuery('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: 3236
                });
            } else if (position >= 2403 && position <= 3236) {
                jQuery('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: 6430
                });
            } else if (position >= 3236 && position <= 6430) {
                jQuery('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: 7320
                });
            } else if (position >= 7191) {
                jQuery('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                });
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Have you referenced the jquery library?

Comment: What version of IE and jQuery?

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: think you need the px for scrollTop: `scrollTop: '6430px'`

Comment: @Rui use jQuery v1.9.1 and IE11

Answer (score 6):

Some browsers use `body` to scroll the document, others use the `documentElement` instead. (This is actually why you have to use `'html, body'` to animate the `scrollTop`)

To get the scroll position in a cross-browser manner, use:

```
position = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```